Excel Calculation
Column A has a 'date' in or 'Allocation Block' in
Column B has a 'date' in
My formula to see how many days are between both is below
=(@columnB))-(@columnA)
However, how can I ensure if Column A has 'Allocation Block' it will show blank instead of #VALUE!
Thanks in advance

Unless your data are not on the same row, this should work =IF(A2="allocation","",B2-A2).

Assuming ColumnA starts in A1 and ColumnB is in B1, you can use
=IF(A1="Allocation Block","",B1-A1)

This checks if A1 has the value 'Allocation Block' and if it does, sets the cell value to an empty string. If it doesn't contain 'Allocation Block', it performs the date difference calculation.
